# Keyboard Shortcut to exit out of text area from within IntelliJ IDEA settings?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-14

While within any **textarea** within a IntelliJ Modal Panel, I find it impossible to get out (Click OK/Apply) using a keyboard shortcut.

- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1
- Mac OS X Yosemite

e.g.
[image: Editing a Live Template within IntelliJ Preferences]

Comment: CTRL+Tab works for me (Yosemite, IntelliJ 14.1)

Comment: how about `Alt + O` ?

Comment: You are right @BohuslavBurghardt. CTRL+Tab does let me get out of the text area. But focus is not on OK.

Comment: @vikingsteve. Alt + O doesn't work for me at all. This is one of the biggest frustrations in Mac the Alt key to access menus and buttons as in windows. The option/alt key is used to enter special characters. For e.g. 'ø' This is the character added by Alt + O in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best answer, but you can hit `Ctrl + Tab` six times followed by `Space`.